# How to make players only place blocks in a certain place and not able to break them?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a speedrun marketplace map thing where you have to cover a bedwars bed as fast as you can for a speedrun so I'm trying to make it so you can only place blocks in that area and not anywhere else. I also want to know how to make it so that you can only place blocks and not break blocks.

Comment: Removing the ability to break blocks can be achieved giving every player a high level of Mining Fatigue

Comment: I think there's something you can do with Adventure mode. Otherwise pinckerman's suggestion is probably not bad, as long as you aren't planning to incorporate PVP because mining fatigue also slows your attack speed if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done by getting a Allow block like this:

```
/give @p allow
```

This Allow block will let you place block on it but no one can break it (except the owner and people with OP).